# Maximising a function by finding roots of the derivative is too slow

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization, special-functions

I have the function `r11[t,k]` defined as follows

```
m20[t_, k_] := 
  1/2 (Erf[Sqrt[t]] + 4 t (t + 1) Erfc[Sqrt[t]] - 2 (1 + 2 t) Sqrt[t/Pi] Exp[-t]);
m02[t_, k_] := (1 - Exp[-4 k t])/(2 k);
m11[t_, k_] := (k^2 - k - 1)/k^3 + 
   Sqrt[2 k + 1]/k^3 Erf[Sqrt[t (2 k + 1)]] + 
   2 (k - 1)/k^2 Sqrt[t/Pi] Exp[-(2 k + 1) t] + (1 - k (k - 1) (2 t + 1))/
     k^3 Exp[-2 k t] Erfc[Sqrt[t]] + 
   2/k NIntegrate[(Exp[-(t - s)]/Sqrt[Pi (t - s)] + 
        Erf[Sqrt[t - s]]) (2 Exp[-s] Sqrt[s/Pi] - (2 s + 1) Erfc[Sqrt[s]]) Exp[-2 k s], 
          {s, 0, t}];

 r11[t_, k_] := m11[t, k]/Sqrt[m20[t, k] m02[t, k]];
```

I want to find its extremum by solving the appropriate equation for some fixed value of time $t=1$.

```
NSolve[D[r11[1, k], k] == 0, k]
```

The computation takes long time and doesn't finish at all. Is there a way to speed it up?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use NMaximize or NMinimize instead of solving for the derivative?

Comment: Thank you. This command NMaximize[{r11[1, k], k > 0}, k] returned me a satisfactory value, but took some time for that.

Comment: You may also want to "protect" the input to the function that uses `NIntegrate` using `NumericQ`, i.e. `m11[t_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ] := (* your code *)`. That will also get rid of the otherwise inevitable warnings. See also [User-defined functions, numerical approximation, and NumericQ](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/27951)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Why don't you go ahead and post a simple answer? The question needed an appropriate title but then it could be helpful for other visitors as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find a local extremum of a function, you could use `NMaximize` or `NMinimize`, instead of looking for a root of the derivative. However, the slow-down in numerically solving this problem is coming from repeatedly calling `m11[t,k]` which needs to numerically integrate on each call.

```
m20[t_, k_] := 
  1/2 (Erf[Sqrt[t]] + 4 t (t + 1) Erfc[Sqrt[t]] - 
     2 (1 + 2 t) Sqrt[t/Pi] Exp[-t]);
m02[t_, k_] := (1 - Exp[-4 k t])/(2 k);
m11[t_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ] := (k^2 - k - 1)/k^3 + 
   Sqrt[2 k + 1]/k^3 Erf[Sqrt[t (2 k + 1)]] + 
   2 (k - 1)/k^2 Sqrt[
     t/Pi] Exp[-(2 k + 1) t] + (1 - k (k - 1) (2 t + 1))/
     k^3 Exp[-2 k t] Erfc[Sqrt[t]] + 
   2/k NIntegrate[(Exp[-(t - s)]/Sqrt[Pi (t - s)] + 
        Erf[Sqrt[t - s]]) (2 Exp[-s] Sqrt[s/Pi] - (2 s + 1) Erfc[
          Sqrt[s]]) Exp[-2 k s], {s, 0, t}];
r11[t_, k_] := m11[t, k]/Sqrt[m20[t, k] m02[t, k]];
```

If you want to search for the root of the derivative, you can use `FindRoot`

```
FindRoot[D[r11[1, k], k], {k, 1}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {14.8238, {k -> 1.15773}} *)
```

Or you search directly for the maximum

```
NMaximize[{r11[1, k], k > 0}, k] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {33.5729, {0.95293, {k -> 1.15773}}} *)
```

You see that in this case, `FindRoot` is faster, but 14 seconds is still not hyperspeed and the reason is the `NIntegrate` inside your code. Both results appear to be correct.

```
Plot[r11[1, k], {k, 0.1, 3}, PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 1, 
 Epilog -> {Line[{{1.1577, 0}, {1.1577, 1}}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method to speed things up for you. First, notice that simply restricting the argument patterns of `m11` as in the community answer means that the derivative of `m11` needs to be computed numerically (which is slow, because the definition of `m11` already includes a numerical integration):

```
Clear[m11]
m11[t_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ] := (k^2-k-1)/k^3 + Sqrt[2 k+1]/k^3 Erf[Sqrt[t (2 k+1)]] +
    2 (k-1)/k^2 Sqrt[t/Pi] Exp[-(2 k+1) t] +
    (1-k (k-1) (2 t+1))/k^3 Exp[-2 k t] Erfc[Sqrt[t]] + 
    2/k NIntegrate[
        (Exp[-(t-s)]/Sqrt[Pi (t-s)]+Erf[Sqrt[t-s]]) * 
        (2 Exp[-s] Sqrt[s/Pi]-(2 s+1) Erfc[Sqrt[s]]) * Exp[-2 k s],
        {s, 0, t}
    ]

D[m11[1, k], k]

% /. k->1. //AbsoluteTiming
```

> Derivative[0, 1][m11][1, k]
>
> {0.732255, -0.190263}

Instead, let's inactivate the integral in the definition of `m11`:

```
Clear[m11]
m11[t_, k_] := (k^2-k-1)/k^3 + Sqrt[2 k+1]/k^3 Erf[Sqrt[t (2 k+1)]] +
    2 (k-1)/k^2 Sqrt[t/Pi] Exp[-(2 k+1) t] +
    (1-k (k-1) (2 t+1))/k^3 Exp[-2 k t] Erfc[Sqrt[t]] + 
    2/k Inactive[NIntegrate][
        (Exp[-(t-s)]/Sqrt[Pi (t-s)]+Erf[Sqrt[t-s]]) * 
        (2 Exp[-s] Sqrt[s/Pi]-(2 s+1) Erfc[Sqrt[s]]) * Exp[-2 k s],
        {s, 0, t}
    ]
```

Now, the derivative of `m11` is a bit more complicated:

```
dm11 = D[m11[1, k], k]
```

> (-1 + 2 k)/k^3 - (3 (-1 - k + k^2))/k^4 + (2 E^(-1 - 2 k))/(
>    k^3 Sqrt[[Pi]]) - (4 E^(-1 - 2 k) (-1 + k))/(k^3 Sqrt[[Pi]]) + (
>    2 E^(-1 - 2 k))/(k^2 Sqrt[[Pi]]) - (4 E^(-1 - 2 k) (-1 + k))/(
>    k^2 Sqrt[[Pi]]) + Erf[Sqrt[1 + 2 k]]/(k^3 Sqrt[1 + 2 k]) - (
>    3 Sqrt[1 + 2 k] Erf[Sqrt[1 + 2 k]])/k^4 + (
>    E^(-2 k) (-3 (-1 + k) - 3 k) Erfc[1])/k^3 - (
>    3 E^(-2 k) (1 - 3 (-1 + k) k) Erfc[1])/k^4 - (
>    2 E^(-2 k) (1 - 3 (-1 + k) k) Erfc[1])/k^3 - (
>    2 Inactive[NIntegrate][
>      E^(-2 k s) (E^(-1 + s)/(Sqrt[[Pi]] Sqrt[1 - s]) + Erf[Sqrt[1 - s]]) ((
>         2 E^-s Sqrt[s])/Sqrt[[Pi]] - (1 + 2 s) Erfc[Sqrt[s]]), {s, 0, 
>       1}])/k^2 + (
>    2 Inactive[NIntegrate][-2 E^(-2 k s)
>        s (E^(-1 + s)/(Sqrt[[Pi]] Sqrt[1 - s]) + Erf[Sqrt[1 - s]]) ((
>         2 E^-s Sqrt[s])/Sqrt[[Pi]] - (1 + 2 s) Erfc[Sqrt[s]]), {s, 0, 1}])/k

On the other hand, evaluating the above expression for a numerical value of `k` only entails a couple numerical integrations. That is, there is no numerical derivative of a function that also includes a numerical integration. So:

```
Activate[dm11 /. k->1] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.028246, -0.190263}

We get the same result, but it is about 25 times faster. Similarly, we can differentiate `r11[t,k]` now since the numerical integration is inactive, and define a function to activate the integration after setting the values of the arguments to numerical values:

```
With[{a1=t_, a2=k_?NumericQ, rhs = D[r11[t,k], k]},
    dr11[a1, a2] := Activate[rhs]
]
```

The [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With) statement is needed to inject the derivative into the downvalue, but the somewhat obscure `a1` and `a2` are used to avoid having the patterns automatically modularized. That is, the version without `a1` and `a2` produces a downvalue like `foo[t$_, k$_?NumericQ] := ...` instead of `foo[t_, k_?NumericQ] := ...`.

Now, we are ready to use your [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot):

```
FindRoot[foo[1,  k], {k, 1}] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.744606, {k -> 1.15773}}

Quite a bit faster than the version using a pattern restriction with an active [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate).